The proof of Theorem 4.6 in Complex Analysis by Elias M. Stein and Rami Shakarchi
I'm reading the book Complex Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi, and I have a question regarding the proof of Theorem 4.6.
The statement of Theorem 4.6 is as follows:
There exist complex numbers $c_1$ and $c_2$ so that the conformal map $F$ of the upper plane $\mathbb{H}$ to polygon $P$ is given by
$$
F(z) = c_1 S(z) + c_2
$$
where $S$ is the Schwarz-Christoffel integral introduced in Section 4.2. The form of the Schwarz-Christoffel integral is
$$
S(z) = \int_{0}^{z} \frac{d\zeta}{(\zeta - A_1)^{\beta_1} \cdots (\zeta - A_n)^{\beta_n}}.
$$
Specifically, the proof claims that
$$
F'(z) = \alpha_k h_k(z)^{-\beta_k} h_k'(z)
$$
and
$$
F''(z) = -\beta_k \alpha_k h_k(z)^{-\beta_k - 1} \left( h_k'(z) \right)^2 + \alpha_k h_k(z)^{-\beta_k} h_k''(z),
$$
where $a_k$ is the vertex of the polygon $P$,
$\alpha_k$ is the interior angle at the vertex $a_k$,
$$\alpha_k + \beta_k = 1,$$
and
$$
h_k(z) = \left( F(z) - a_k \right)^{1/\alpha_k},
$$
which is the definition of $h_k$. The domain of $h_k$ is extended to the strip $A_{k-1} < \mathrm{Re}(z) < A_{k+1}$ from the upper half-plane of the strip $A_{k-1} < \mathrm{Re}(z) < A_{k+1}$ by applying the Schwarz reflection principle.
From this, the expression
$$
\frac{F''(z)}{F'(z)} = -\frac{\beta_k}{z - A_k} + E_k(z)
$$
is derived where $E_k(z)$ is a holomorphic function in the strip $A_{k-1} < \mathrm{Re}(z) < A_{k+1}$.
However, it seems that
$$
\lim_{z \to A_k} \frac{F''(z)}{F'(z)}(z - A_k) = -\frac{\beta_k}{\alpha_k}
$$
because
$$
\frac{F''(z)}{F'(z)} = -\frac{\beta_k h_k'(z)}{h_k(z)} + \frac{h_k''(z)}{h_k'(z)}
$$
and
$$
\frac{F'(z)}{F(z) - F(A_k)} = \alpha_k \frac{h_k'(z)}{h_k(z)}.
$$
Could someone help clarify this discrepancy?

Welcome to the site. This question has insufficient context. I can sort of guess at the pieces but really you should present what the theorem statement is and what $F$ and $h$ are. Not everyone has a copy of your edition of the book with them.. this will make your question more answerable and also more readable by future learners

You may, and should, edit this into the question body rather than the comments. At the base of the question, below where it shows the tag "complex-analysis", there is an edit button you are free to use at any time

Thank you for your comment. I have edited it.

you are sure of the form of $F''(z)=...$, there is a difference in notation but it is easy to accommodate, see: https://archive.org/details/smirnov-a-course-of-higher-mathematics-vol-3-2-complex-variables-special-functions/Smirnov%20-%20A%20Course%20of%20Higher%20Mathematics%20-%20Vol%203-2%20-%20Complex%20Variables%20Special%20Functions/page/149/mode/1up?view=theater

I’m not sure about this form with $h_k$ for $F’(z)$. Surely it should involve all indices $k$, perhaps as a sum. Could you define $h_k$ for us? $F’(z)$ should just be, for $z$ away from $A_1,\cdots$, $c_1\prod_k(z-A_k)^{-\beta_k}$ no? That said, I don’t think the integral is well-defined independently of the path $0\to z$ unless $\beta_k$ is an integer strictly bigger than $1$ for all $k$.

I have edited it again. I have added the explanation of $h_k$. $F(z)$ is the conformal map given from the beginning.
